# Slick addState java.lang.Error

Tags: java

Ok, so I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out what. I'm following a tutorial about building a simple game with Slick. I know there is almost nothing in the code, but at this point the code should be able to compile.

```
package javagame;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
public class Game extends StateBasedGame{

    public static final String gamename = "Game name!";
    public static final int menu = 0;
    public static final int play = 1;

    public Game(String gamename){
        super(gamename);
        this.addState(new Menu(menu));
        this.addState(new Play(play));  
    }

    public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException{
        this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
        this.getState(play).init(gc, this);
        this.enterState(menu);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppGameContainer appgc;
        try{
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
            appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 360, false);
            appgc.start();
        }catch(SlickException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

And here are the classes

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Play {

    public Play(int state){
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{ 
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
    }

    public int getID(){ 
        return 1;
    }

}
```

and

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Menu {

    public Menu(int state){
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
    }

    public int getID(){ 
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method addState(GameState) in the type StateBasedGame is not applicable for the arguments (Menu)
    The method addState(GameState) in the type StateBasedGame is not applicable for the arguments (Play)

    at javagame.Game.<init>(Game.java:12)
    at javagame.Game.main(Game.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Game extends `StateBasedGame` and it does not override `addState()`, when you say `this.addState(new Menu(menu));` it is trying to call method defined in `StateBasedGame` [API referance](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/state/StateBasedGame.html#addState(org.newdawn.slick.state.GameState))

So your `Menu` and `Play` class should be sub class of `GameState`